# Python automatically matching named parameters

Tags: python

Is there any way to pass parameters to a Python function such that if the variable name matches the parameter name, the function will ensure the input is correct?

Let's say I have a function as such:

```
def func(foo, bar):
    return do_something_with(foo, bar)
```

and I wanted to call it as such:

```
foo = get_foo()
bar = get_bar()
ret_val = func(foo=foo, bar=bar)
```

I can do this, but I feel like when the parameter name and the variable name are the same, there should be some mechanism to automatically match up the parameters (like NATURAL JOIN in SQL). Is there any such mechanism?

Comment: This feels like it should be possible to check with a lint rule for many (most?) cases. Unfortunately, I do not have experience writing these.

Comment: How about using kwargs instead of variable names? `kwargs = {}; kwargs['foo'] = get_foo(); kwargs['bar'] = get_bar(); ret_val=func(**kwargs)`

Comment: Then just use kwargs? but I have a feeling this is an xy problem anyway.

Comment: Why not just call the function without the keywords, given that it is not defined to require them: `ret_val = func(foo, bar)`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no special function call syntax to pass variables as keyword arguments of the same name. If that's how you want to call your function, you must write `func(foo=foo, bar=bar)`. While there are a few ways you could work around the issue, they're all so much worse than just writing the keywords out that I wouldn't recommend them.

As an example of a bad workaround, you could define your function to take arbitrary extra keyword arguments (with `def func(foo, bar, **kwargs_to_be_ignored)`) and then call the function with `func(**locals())`. That will pass in every local variable in your namespace as a keyword argument. In the body of some functions with few local variables, this might be reasonably clean, but in many other contexts (especially at the global level) it will very often pass a whole mess of unnecessary stuff. And if your function has optional arguments (e.g. `def func(foo, bar, baz='default)`) you can wind up accidentally passing in an overriding value to an argument you didn't want to pass if you just happen to have a variable with that argument's name in your local namespace.

Answer (score 3):

`*` is the usual way of doing this, forcing the caller to provide names for the arguments

```py
def func(*, foo, bar)
```

see [PEP 3102 – Keyword-Only Arguments (`*`)](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/) and [PEP 570 – Python Positional-Only Parameters
(`/`)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/) for the inverse

You might also consider using a dict `**kwargs` which forces the input to have the correct *keys*

```py
def func(**kwargs):
    foo = kwargs.pop("foo")
    bar = kwargs.pop("bar")
    if kwargs:
        raise ValueError(f"unexpected unused arguments: {kwargs}")
    ...
```

Practically popping from `kwargs` can be useful to maintain Python 2.x compatibility or potentially help transition legacy callers (for example by also accepting a subset of positional or `*args` and warning for members), but prefer PEP 3102 `*` if you can (available in every version of Python 3)!

---

However, generally, don't try to "force" or "help" callers of your function use it properly and leave how they call it up to them!

Python's flexibility goes both ways and callers can easily get the signature right by simply providing the arguments if they want to, or misuse your function in surprising ways, such as [calling `inspect.getsource()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) dynamically rewriting your function and clobbering the original name

That said, also try not to break callers in non-obvious ways if you're writing a library, say by switching the order of two inputs of the same type and not validating them!

Answer (score 1):

Python has a concept of positional arguments and keyword arguments, but they are just labels. Especially with positional arguments -- Python does not (and cannot) care about the names of the variables you're using, but rather their order.

In your case, the following might be solutions, but they all have tradeoffs:

```py
def func(*, foo, bar):
    """
    Keyword arguments only (note the leading star "*")

    Advantage: callers must specify which parameter they mean.

    Disadvantage: callers MUST specify which parameter they mean,
                  which can be verbose.
    """

    pass


def func(foo, bar):
    """
    Positional arguments allowed

    Advantage: callers can be terse, as in `func(foo, bar)` is valid.

    Disadvantage: those terse calls could easily be `func(bar, foo)`.
    """

    pass
```

Comment: It can (for example by checking `locals()` or `globals()`), it just not gonna be very efficient

Comment: `def func(foo, bar)` allows the arguments either as positional or as keywords. For positional arguments only it's `def func(foo, bar, /)`. See PEP 570: https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/

Comment: @slothrop you're right of course, but here it doesn't actually matter. `func(bar, foo)` doesn't have the desired output no matter what, so really the choice is whether you allow them to be positional or not. That said: the "Only" in my docstring is misleading -- I will edit.